# Inline style using asset pipeline in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

```html
<%= link_to root_path do %>
    <div class="">
        <div style="background-image:<%= image_tag " image1.png "%>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to pull the image from the asset pipeline to put as my background.
I could do it in .sass file.  But I made a template for each one and think it would be easier to input each photo in.

`<div style="background-image:<%= image_tag "image1.png"%>">`
 This is the line that I'm sure about the syntax about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ERB` to be interpreted by asset pipeline, then `asset_path 'image.png'` will return the full path of the image located in one of the asset load paths, which you can then use inside `url()`. So your inline `div` may look like:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image1.png' %>)">
```

Ref: [CSS and ERB](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb) (note the `underscore (_)` in `asset_path` helper)

---

If you use `Sass`, the following helpers will help you to make it more concise:

- `image-url("rails.png")` returns `url(/assets/rails.png)`
- `image-path("rails.png")` returns `"/assets/rails.png"`

The more generic form can also be used:

- `asset-url("rails.png")` returns `url(/assets/rails.png)`
- `asset-path("rails.png")` returns `"/assets/rails.png"`

Ref: [CSS and Sass](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) (note the `dash (-)` in above helpers)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `image_path` which would give you an `img` tag, for something to give you the path for the `image1` file, try with `image_path`:

```
<div style="background-image: <%= image_path 'image1' %>"></div>
```

Comment: Good catch on using `image_path` instead of `image_tag`. The image doesn't at all.  I'm using rails5 not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use non-inline style, then you can also use `image-path`  at .scss.

At html.erb

```
<div class="custom-background"></div>
```

At .scss

```
.custom-background {
 background-image: image-path('image1.png');
}
```